# Between "this" object and CurrentThread in constructor

Tags: java, multithreading

While doing some practices on multi-threading, I found that I can not set the name of the thread in my code. I can use `this` to refer the current object then why I can not use Thread.currentThread while constructing thread to access current thread. I am bit confusing. please help me.

**When actually thread creating? Is it when constructing thread instance or while calling method start() on thread?**

what is currentThread means here?

```
public class RecursiveRunnableTest {

    public static void main(String... args){
        Thread t =  new Thread(new RecursiveRunnable("First thread"));
        t.start();
    }


}

class RecursiveRunnable implements Runnable {

    private String name;
    public RecursiveRunnable(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        Thread.currentThread().setName(this.name); // Expecting to set the name of thread here
    }
    @Override
    public synchronized void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()); // displaying Thread-0
        System.out.println(this.name); // displaying "First thread"

        try{
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `this`, in your code, is the instance of RecursiveRunnable, not the thread

Comment: By the way, don’t declare the `run` method as `synchronized`. In the best case, it will be obsolete. But you may get surprising results when doing this in more complex code.

Comment: @Holger, I am actually playing with multi threading. I found this difference.

Comment: @dystroy, agreed, this is instance. If I understand correct, RecursiveRunnable, then in constructor current thread should be a thread. Am I correct?

Answer (score 2):

Simply because main thread constructs it not the t thread constructs itself. So, you may rewrite to this one (setting thread's name before starting it):

```
public class RecursiveRunnableTest {

    public static void main(String... args){
        RecursiveRunnable rr = new RecursiveRunnable("First thread");
        Thread t =  new Thread(rr);
        t.setName(rr.getName());
        t.start();
    }


}

class RecursiveRunnable implements Runnable{

    private String name;
    public RecursiveRunnable(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName(){return this.name;}
    @Override
    public synchronized void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()); // displaying Thread-0
        System.out.println(this.name); // displaying "First thread"

        try{
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For whatever it's worth, setting the thread name like this is not Thread safe.

Comment: @JohnVint, what about `t.setName` before `t.start`.

Comment: Yes, that is thread safe.  Writes that occur prior to starting the thread are visible after the start.  This is actually a bug in the JDK, the underlying `char[]` for the name is neither synchronized nor volatile.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this instead

```
Thread t = new Thread(new RecursiveRunnable("First thread"));
t.start();
Thread.sleep(1L);
System.out.println("main thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName()); // same thread that created the RecrusiveRunnable instance
```

you will see

```
main thread: First thread
```

printed.
This is because the main thread builds the `RecursiveRunnable`, so

```
Thread.currentThread().setName(this.name);
```

is actually changing the name of the main thread, not the thread that the `Runnable` will eventually run in.

---

Also

```
System.out.println(this.name); // displaying "First thread"
```

is referring to the `name` field of the `RecursiveRunnable` object, which you've set to the same value as the main thread.